# Dynamically set properties of contorls in gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview which has a textbox in an itemtemplate. I want to set the maxlength property of this textbox dynamically.

The code I have now is -

```
<asp:GridView ID="grd" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                    OnRowDataBound="grd_RowDataBound" >
                    <Columns>                        
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Textbox">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtValue" Text="" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Columns="8" Rows="3"></asp:TextBox>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

My code in the RowDataBound event handler -

```
protected void grd_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {            
                if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)  
                {                    
                    TextBox txtText = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtValue");  

                    txtText.Text = "test";  //this works fine

                    txtText.MaxLength = 10;    //this does not work. 
                }         
        }
```

Does anyone know why I am not able to set the MaxLength property dynamically? And, how can I set the value of a property of the control in gridview dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A multiline textbox can't have a MaxLength.
Although you wont get any error but it won't work.

You can try changing the TextMode of textbox to SingleLine to see if it would work.

Comment: Had my common sense prevailed, I would have saved the time I spent on this.. :) Thanks, you are right.